# Negotiating ArcPy schema locks in script

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, schema-locks, error-000464

How do I avoid the 000464 (Cannot get exclusive schema lock) error in this code caused by the last line?

```
import arcpy
import os

geodatabase = 'C:/Data/testgdb.gdb'
fc_name = 'test_feature_class'

fields = [
    ['name', 'TEXT', 'Name', 32],
    ['other', 'TEXT', 'Other', 32]
]

if not arcpy.Exists(geodatabase):
    gdb_path, gdb_filename = os.path.split(geodatabase)
    print(gdb_path, gdb_filename)
    gdb_name, gdb_extension = os.path.splitext(gdb_filename)
    print(gdb_name, gdb_extension)
    gdb = arcpy.CreateFileGDB_management(gdb_path, gdb_name)

if not arcpy.Exists(os.path.join(geodatabase, fc_name)):
    fc = arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management(geodatabase, fc_name, 'POINT', spatial_reference=arcpy.SpatialReference(4326))
    ## THE BELOW LINE TRIGGERS ERROR 000464: Cannot get exclusive schema lock.  Either being edited or in use by another application or service. ##
    arcpy.AddFields_management(fc, fields)
```

Interestingly, the entire code executes without issue if I delete the entire geodatabase between runs (not an option for production, just an observation).

If I remove the offending `arcpy.AddFields_management()` method call, the code will create the feature class in the existing geodatabase without error (and without schema).  But I cannot call `AddFields_management()` on the feature class created in the existing database without having it raise a schema lock error.

Comment: Instead of `fc = arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management(etc...)` try `fc = arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management(etc...).getOutput(0)`.  Because in your original code, `fc` is not a featureclass, but a [`Result` object](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/classes/result.htm).

Comment: Hi @user2856 , that didn't work. Still gives me the same error.